# jQuery total number of lines for a speaker

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

Error with code;

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    loadPlay();

    $("#term_search").focus(function(event) {
  $(this).val("");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`var total_num_words = 0;` is set and not set again before the `prepend()` output.

Comment: how do i set it before prepend() ?

Comment: With an equal sign. 
You need to assign something to total_num_words it to display something other than 0.

Right now your program looks like: x=0; Print x;
And then you're asking why is my x 0?

Comment: put the equal sign where exactly

Comment: @user2321845 there seems to be no calculation of the number of lines. Where should this come from?